# Remove checked row Angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, row

I have a list of field in row. The user can add the row. How can I make a function which removes the checked rows? I was thinking to add to them in a new array, but I don't know how to filter the selected item.

http://plnkr.co/edit/S2tudP0kJcVUiKZKRa7j?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="DuplicateInputCtrl" class="container">
<div data-ng-repeat="food in foods">
  <div class="form-group title-field">
    <label for="">Food</label>
    <select class="form-control input-full" data-ng-model="food.Selection"
        data-ng-options="foodType.code as foodType.type for foodType in foodTypes">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden">
    <button data-ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="btn delete-field-{{$index}}">
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

        <input style="background: white; color: black;" type="text" id="myInput"  class="form-control" data-ng-model="food.Text"/>
```

```
    </div>
</div>
{{foods | json}}
<button data-ng-click="cloneItem()" class="btn inline">
  Add
</button>    
    <button data-ng-click="" class="btn inline">
  Remove Selected
</button>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 $scope.removeSelected = function() {
            $scope.foods = $scope.foods.filter(function(food){
                return !food.selected
            })
          }
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ncIzToMhtglmSp2fVXfk?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! But i was thiking to add it in new array because i want to implements that script with with another one, that generate a barcode for each row pressing the button "UPDATE".. but how can i do it just for the checked one? http://plnkr.co/edit/v9ETdTA5dJhFl7IX0kpY?p=preview

Because at the end i will do just a unique button that print in a new windows the barcodes of the checked rows

Comment: Why do you want to add the selected items to a new array if you just want to remove them. I don't quite get what you said

Comment: I don't need it, forget it :) I just thought it could help. Anyway, the target that i wanted is: the user can add some rows. At the end of all the table, the user has 2 button: PRINT SELECTED and REMOVE SELECTED. So, if the user check 3 rows, he can remove (and you showed me how with that funciton) and he can print the barcode of these 3 checked rowes. Now, the scirpt that i've made creates the barcode for each rows, everytime you press update

Answer (score 1):

```
Use the following function on remove selected button click
```

```
`$scope.removeSelectedItems = function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.foods.length; i++) {                 
              if ($scope.foods[i].selected == true) {
                  $scope.foods.splice(i, 1);
                  i--; 
              }
          }             
      }`
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this one.